# Foo table in angular 4

Tags: angular, footable

I am planning to implement an Foo table in my angular 4.2 project.
I do not want to use foo table as jquery plugin as it has lot of redrawing and it is not the angular way.

Do we have any angular plugin to use foo table in an angular 4 project. I tried searching on google but did not find one.

OR someone can direct me to some helpful link where I can create my own angular module for the foo-table.

Thanks !!

Comment: Yep. Need this too. I'm trying with material tables, but it's a mess. It's kinda impossible to put accordions between rows